Code for search/filter results in Wix doesn’t work, what's wrong with my code?
To begin with, I don't know much about coding but I've been following a video to include a search functionality in my Wix website.
What’s wrong with my code? The search/filtering doesn't work when I press the search button.
The code also includes a way to reset the search results (using an overlayed button on the search button) and get the page back to its original form.
There seems to be something wrong with the .find() function because it's underlined in red, and I get this message:
"Cannot find name 'find'. Declaration or statement expected."
Here's the code that I'm using:
import wixData from 'wix-data';
$w('#resetButton').hide();

$w.onReady(function () {
    // Any additional setup can be added here.
});

export function searchButton_click(event) {
    search();
}

function search() {
    wixData.query("NewsUpdates")
        .contains("headline", $w('#input5').value)
        .or(wixData.query("NewsUpdates").contains("content", $w('#input5').value))
        .find()
        .then(results => {
            $w('#repeater1').data = results.items;
        });
    $w('#resetButton').show();
    $w('#resetButton').enable();
    $w('#searchButton').hide();
}

export function resetButton_click(event) {
    $w('#dataset1').setFilter(wixData.filter());
    $w('#input5').value = undefined;
    $w('#searchButton').show();
    $w('#searchButton').enable();
    $w('#resetButton').hide();
}


I don't know much about coding, and I've only been fighting with ChatGPT without any solution. I’ve tried finding alternatives to the .find() function, but every solution gives me different errors.
